# show list in razor MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have an entity which has a list of some object and I want to let the user to add as much as he want from that object so that I can put them in the list.
how can I create that in razor view? should I use Ajax and if yes how?

Comment: Can you provide what do you have and what do you want to the user have, so we can see the start and the end... your question is hard to understand regarding the list part...

Comment: And also approve more answered questions from others.... You may get more help. Your rating is only 54% on marking accepted answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may take a look at the [following blog post](http://blog.stevensanderson.com/2010/01/28/editing-a-variable-length-list-aspnet-mvc-2-style/). It was written for ASP.NET MVC 2, but it is very good and those notions still apply in ASP.NET MVC 3. Adapting it to Razor would be trivial.